# How do I make my program repeat the sound every five seconds?

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*
import javax.swing.*;

public class Morning extends JFrame
implements ActionListener

{
  private EasySound rooster;
  private int time;

  public Morning()
    super("Morning");
    rooster = new EasySound("roost.wav");
    rooster.play();

    time = 0;
    Timer clock = new Timer(5000, this);
    clock.start();

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Morning morning = new Morning();
    morning.setSize(300, 150);
    morning.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    morning.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    time++;
  }
}
```

So my question is, how do I make the roost.wav sound play every five seconds. The program compiles, but it doesn't replay after it plays once.

Thanks to whoever helps!
Simone

Comment: That is because you only play it once. The timer you created isn't doing anything.

Comment: You might want to check your curly brackets, specifically the constructor's body. Also, you are missing a semicolon on one of your imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the method actionperformed where you have to put the code that plays the sound. Because its what the timer do, it calls actionperformed periodically.

Comment: thank you so much! Once I read this, it made it seem so obvious. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You only play the sound when you create a Morning object, and since you only create a single Morning object in your code, the sound only plays once. You either need to create more Morning objects, or move the code that plays the sound to the actionPerformed() method.